# Properly indexing an array field?

Tags: mongodb

I'm working with a database that has the following document design:

```
{
    'email':    'a@b.com',
    'credentials': [{
        'type':     'password',
        'content':  'hashedpassword'
    }, {
        'type':     'oauth2',
        'content':  'token'
    }]
}
```

I have indexed `{credentials.type: 1, credentials.content: 1}`. It's properly picked up, but the performance is bad on a 50k document collection.

Here is the log indicating the query plan:

```
[conn73] command database.users command: find {
    find: "users",
    filter: {
        credentials.type: "type",
        credentials.content: "content"
    },
    limit: 1,
    batchSize: 1,
    singleBatch: true
}
planSummary: IXSCAN {
    credentials.type: 1,
    credentials.content: 1
}
keysExamined:20860
docsExamined:18109
cursorExhausted:1
keyUpdates:0
writeConflicts:0
numYields:163
nreturned:1
reslen:455
locks:{
    Global: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 328
        }
    },
    Database: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 164
        }
    },
    Collection: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 164
        }
    }
}
protocol:op_query
331ms
```

I noticed I have a high number of keysExamined and docsExamined. I understand mongodb is capable of putting all values in the array to build that index. Why would it have to scan so many keys?

I do have high concurrent accesses, but to read only.

Below is explain() result of the query:

```
> db.users.find({'credentials.type': 'abc', 'credentials.content': 'def'}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "net.users",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "credentials.type" : {
                        "$eq" : "abc"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "credentials.content" : {
                        "$eq" : "def"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "credentials.content" : {
                    "$eq" : "def"
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "credentials.type" : 1,
                    "credentials.content" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "credentials.type_1_credentials.content_1",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "credentials.type" : [
                        "[\"abc\", \"abc\"]"
                    ],
                    "credentials.content" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.11",
        "gitVersion" : "009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I'm running mongodb v3.2.11 . How do I properly optimize this query? Should I alter the document design?

Comment: along with existing index {credentials.type: 1, credentials.content: 1} you can have an index on {credentials:1}

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your query and on desired resulting document(s) ? also please post the query.explain()

Comment: @SergiuZaharie I have updated to include query explain.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to separate the credentials into different docs.

such as:

```
{
    'email':    'a@b.com',
    'credentialType':     'password',
    'credentialContent':  'hashedpassword'
}

{
     'email':    'a@b.com',
     'credentialType':     'oauth2',
     'credentialContent':  'token'
}
```

and create indexes on credentialType and credentialContent.

This way you will have more document but more clear indexes. you query will run faster. Because it does not need to deal with array of obj.

Comment: Is there any reference on how array object indexes should be slow?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint by Sergiu Zaharie, I'm able to re-look at the index issue.

It turns out that because of 'credentials.type' are all similar, and 'credentials.content' are all different, I should put the compound index on 'credentials.content' first.

In other words, `{credentials.content: 1, credentials.type: 1}` is the answer here.

Comment: The order of fields in the query does not matter when using a compund index, it matters only on sort. examples here https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index

Comment: It looks like indexing on a unique field results in better performance than indexing on a field with handful of choices. I originally thought the order didn't matter, nor have I learned otherwise elsewhere. I assumed indexed fields are concatenated, but it wasn't the case either. It seems that the first field in the index is very important, and it's better be close to unique.